# I just updated from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and I'm having a problem with scrolling

Tags: 14.04, unity, mouse, scrolling, scrollbar

I just updated from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and I'm having a problem with scrolling.

The problem is the mouse click to scroll a page at a time has swapped from the old left click to page up down to right click to page up down, left clicking ends up is some random movement which baffles me. This changing round click bit is really bugging me on Firefox.  Its not all that fun on other Apps either. I have been looking all over for info on this one but no luck at all.

I have now noticed there are a few Apps where the old left click still gets a page at a time and right clicking on the scrollbar background does nothing.  This bugs me even more than the changed buttons as I would probably get used to the new way if it was setup that way everywhere but with it applied randomly, I know I can never get used to doing things one way here and there and another way in other Apps.

Anyway if anyone has any idea what so ever please help.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.